# JAVA static classes

Tags: java, static, static-methods

I have a class that is extending `JDBCRealm` class and implementing `Realm` interface:

```
public class TomcatRealm extends JDBCRealm implements Realm {}
```

My question is how do I make the outer class static i.e., I be able to call the methods of `JDBCRealm` class without instantiating the `TomcatRealm` class.

**Edit 1:**

I see that many people are not getting the intent of the question. I actually want to call a method of `JDBCRealm` class from inside a static method in `TomcatRealm`. Ex:

```
private static String getCredCol() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return getUserCredCol();
}
//This static method cannot hide the instance method from `JDBCRealm`
```

**Edit 2:**

In another question somebody suggested that I instantiate `JDBCRealm` and then call its methods in the `TomcatRealm` static methods. I have already tried this and facing an issue: [JDBCRealm getConnectionURL() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406271/jdbcrealm-getconnectionurl-returns-null)

As a workaround of that problem, I thought of trying this.

Comment: You want to do some research into "singletons"

Comment: You want to do what?

Comment: @JoeC be able to call the methods of JDBCRealm class without instantiating the TomcatRealm class

Comment: Why would you want to create a class if you don't want to instantiate it?

Comment: Why won't you simply instantiate JDBCRealm and use this?

Comment: So you're saying you want to call something like `JDBCRealm.instanceMethod()` directly?  Because you can't do that.

Comment: if you are any way extending JDBCRealm then you can refer all methods (that are protected, final) of JDBCRealm in your class directly

Comment: @HBK You don't have to. Just mark the methods `static`. But it's not clear what you exactly want; this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Neo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406271/jdbcrealm-getconnectionurl-returns-null

Comment: @Optional agreed... but no static method inside `TomcatRealm` class shall be able to call methods of `JDBCRealm` class

Comment: Yes, you can't call it. So if you can modify JDBCRealm then make those methods static, else have a static instance of JDBCRealm in your class...

private static JDBCRealm proxy ..
then call on proxy

Comment: You can call it with `JDBCRealm.getUserCredCol()` but this is not going to help you with your Y problem.

Comment: @MCEmperor Problem X: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406271/jdbcrealm-getconnectionurl-returns-null

Comment: @Optional I already tried that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406271/jdbcrealm-getconnectionurl-returns-null

Comment: @Oleg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406271/jdbcrealm-getconnectionurl-returns-null

Comment: Why do you want to extend JDCBRealm?

Comment: @matt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406271/jdbcrealm-getconnectionurl-returns-null

Answer (score 1):

you can't make outer class as static but you may do this, Have a look..

```js
interface Realm {

}

class JDBCRealm {
 protected static void m1() {
  System.out.println(" protected Static method m1 of class JDBCRealm ..");
 }

 public static void m2() {
  System.out.println(" public Static method m2 of class JDBCRealm ..");
 }

}

public class TomcatRealm extends JDBCRealm implements Realm {
 public static void main(String... args) {
  JDBCRealm .m1();// protected Static method m1 of class JDBCRealm ..
  JDBCRealm .m2();// public Static method m2 of class JDBCRealm ..

 }

}
```

Comment: The `JDBCRealm` class is a well-defined class which has concrete methods that I need to re-use. I want to use the existing methods of `JDBCRealm`

Comment: TomcatRealm  t1= new TomcatRealm ();  t1.m1(); // you can do this . Otherwise take the help of static nested inner class . it may help